# how to create a toggle div with form button submit and display error on same div?

Tags: javascript, java, php, html

```
<div id="butontogle"> this div is toggled by button
 <form>
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset">Cancel</button>
 </form>
               <?php  echo $erormsg; ?>
</div>
```

When this form find match redirect user to home.
 The problem is when match not found this form hide.
 I want this form to display the error message and hide when a click the toggle    button. Toggle button works fine. Is there a way to work around this submit button to not hide its div.

technically its not a togle function but i call it like that i have button1 and button2  ...
->buton1  show div (butontogle) and hide buton2 same time 
->buton2  hide div (butontogle)  and buton1 same time

they works fine but when i use submit in the div(butontogle)
->match user/pass = home.php
->not match user/pass  hide the div where (it should post mesage there)

thanks a lot for help

Comment: Where is code responsible for hiding the div?

Comment: $('#btns').on('click', function() {
 $('#butontogle').show();
 $('#btns2').show();
 $('#icon3').show();
 $('#icon').hide();
});

Comment: Might want to put your comment into your question, instead of a comment..

Comment: technically its not a togle function but i call it like that i have button1 and button2